# Verify a SHA512 password if($row['password']==hash('SHA512', $upass))

Tags: php, authentication, sha512

When a user creates a account on my website then their password is stored using SHA512. My problem is when the user tries to login with their password, i believe i am verifying the password incorrectly however i cannot see what i have done wrong.

Here is my register script which works :

```
 $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
 $sname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sname']);
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

 $upass = hash('SHA512', $upass);
```

The password 'Test' is stored in the database as:

ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f88

Here is my login script:

```
if($row['password']==hash('SHA512', $upass))
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: account.php");
```

If any body could please edit my login code so that it can retrieve and verify the SHA512 string then it would be greatly appreciated.

I am not worried about totally changing my login system to make it more secure, it is a very simple system which is only used to store a users preferences for the site, please could we just sick to using SHA512.

Comment: Why are you passing $_POST['pass'] to real_escape_string first and then the result to hash()? If anything the order should be reversed.

Comment: Hi, i understand what you mean, i have just reversed it, thanks. however there is still a problem with if($row['password']==hash('SHA512', $upass))

Comment: Can you please for debugging purposes add the line `var_dump($_POST['pass'], $upass, $row['password']);` right before the if-statement and add the output to your question?

Comment: uh, the output of `echo hash('SHA512', 'Test');` on my machine is `c6ee9e33cf5c6715a1d148fd73f7318884b41adcb916021e2bc0e800a5c5dd97f5142178f6ae88c8fdd98e1afb0ce4c8d2c54b5f37b30b7da1997bb33b0b8a31` - quite different from the value in your database,

Comment: **NEVER USE SHA512 FOR PASSWORD HASHING!** Don't try to build you own login system without knowing the basics! Have a short research and simply use one of the existing solutions available, this will stop you from being hacking within microseconds!

Comment: @Sliq , then at least provide some hints on what to look for ;-) 
suggestion: search for systems that use bcrypt or PBKDF2 and had some peer review.

Comment: I am now using password_hash and verify with a cost of 12, is this okay  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is the hash_equals() for php version >= 5.6.0 If you are using lower version then you can use code from below.

```
if(!function_exists('hash_equals')) {
  function hash_equals($str1, $str2) {
    if(strlen($str1) != strlen($str2)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $res = $str1 ^ $str2;
      $ret = 0;
      for($i = strlen($res) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) $ret |= ord($res[$i]);
      return !$ret;
    }
  }
}
```

> Matching hash.

```
$expected  = crypt('Test', '$2a$07$addsomecustomstring$');
$correct   = crypt('Test', '$2a$07$addsomecustomstring$');
$wrong = crypt('tets',  '$2a$07$addsomecustomstring$');

var_dump(hash_equals($expected, $correct)); //true
var_dump(hash_equals($expected, $wrong)); //false
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you already calculated hash above you no longer need to call hash function again in comparison:

```
if($row['password']==$upass)
```

instead of:

```
if($row['password']==hash('SHA512', $upass))
```

Comment: They are separate files, i have replaced if($row['password']==hash('SHA512', $upass))
with if($row['password']==$upass) however there is still a login error