# SHA512 Incorrect Login Retrieving Password From Database

Tags: php, mysql, sha512

OK So I have 2 scripts. One to register users and one for someone to login. I am new to PHP and was on here earlier and it was said to me that I should not use MD5. So here is my attempt to do things the right way and to practice good coding habits from the beginning.

So far I can get the password hashed and in to the database but when I try to login it tells me invalid password. Here is the code I have so far. (PLEASE REMEMBER THAT I AM NEW AND I REALLY AM HAVING A HARD TIME UNDERSTANDING THIS).

This is the Login (I only included the main part of the login where I am having trouble.)

```
     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
     $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
     $password = hash('sha512',$password);
     //Checking is user existing in the database or not
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'
     AND password='".$password."'";
     $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
     $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     if($rows==1){
```

This is the Registration (I only included the main part of this also)

```
//Strip & Escape PW
$password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
$sql_u = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$sql_e = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$res_u = mysqli_query($con, $sql_u);
$res_e = mysqli_query($con, $sql_e);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res_u) > 0) {
$name_error = "Sorry... username already taken";
}
else if(mysqli_num_rows($res_e) > 0){
$email_error = "Sorry... email already taken";
}
else{
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
VALUES ('$username', '$email', '".hash('sha512',$password)."')";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo 'You Have Registered Successfully!<br>
```

BTW I looked at this article already and am completely lost. So if you are gonna flag this as duplicate base on this article can you please let me know what I am missing as I do not understand this article at all. Thank you.

[Verify a SHA512 password if($row['password']==hash('SHA512', $upass))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367850/verify-a-sha512-password-ifrowpassword-hashsha512-upass)

(I read this )

Comment: Why are you stripping slashes and escaping the passwords when you're dealing with password hash? If a user have multiple slashes in their password, you've just weakened it. I would also recommend using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead of hashing it manually (with no salt at all)

Comment: i recommend you use password_hash and Password_verify

Comment: So How do I do that and why is it telling me that password has is deprecated. Please let me know I really look forward to tackling this!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use plain SHA512 hashing for passwords. This is vulnerable to rainbow tables, as it does not include a salt. So same password is same hash.
More at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Anyway, in PHP there is a own function for hashing passwords.
Use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for registration and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for login. This implemention uses Blowfish algorithm.

BTW: maybe change from mysqli to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), but this complicated as beginner

Best regards

Comment: I still dont understand. I am completely lost. I tried using the password verify in my current code but it doesnt work

Comment: Check out this guide: https://www.wdb24.com/how-to-use-php-password_hash-registration-login-form/. Take a look at the login.php file. Do not query the database for username and password, just for username and then use password_verify() function.